# whenever gem is not working for every 2 seconds

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I have implemented whenever gem for my backend crons jobs which is working good when I try something like

```
every 2.seconds do
  rake "my:rake:task"
end
```

I get this error

```
`parse_time': Time must be in minutes or higher (ArgumentError)
```

I really want to run this task after every few seconds how can I do this.

Comment: What does your rake task do?

Comment: it send two requests to third party API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with the `whenever` gem.

Under the hood, the `whenever` gem simply creates a [`cron` job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). These can only be configured at a minimum granularity of per-*minute*.

What you **could** do instead is write a shell script with an infinite loop that runs your task, and then sleeps for 2 seconds. However, I would advise against it - running something this frequently feels wrong. There's probably a much cleaner approach, e.g. running your code as an `after_save` hook?

Answer (score 1):

You got the error because  [this](https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/cron.rb#L88) is the reason

Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute. What you could do is write a shell script with an infinite loop that runs your task, and then sleeps for 2 seconds. That way your task would be run more or less every 2 seconds, depending on how long the task itself takes.

It really does sound like you're doing something that you probably shouldn't be doing though

like by a loop

```
while true ; do cd /home/myrailsapp && rake my:rake:task & ; sleep 2; done
```

Or conrtab will look something like this

and in `/home/myrailsapp/rakescript.sh`

```
cd /home/myrailsapp && rake my:rake:task
```

in corntab

```
* * * * * /home/myrailsapp/rakescript.sh
* * * * * sleep 2; /home/myrailsapp/rakescript.sh
* * * * * sleep 4; /home/myrailsapp/rakescript.sh
* * * * * sleep 6; /home/myrailsapp/rakescript.sh
```

Comment: This should be a comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

A loop with rails runner works fine:

```
loop {
  Ball.update_all_positions
  sleep 2
}
```